# Android BatteryManager.isCharging() always False

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

My code:

```
binding.showButton.setOnClickListener {
    val batteryManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager

    Log.v("xxx", "isCharging: ${batteryManager.isCharging}")    //always false
}
```

Comment: Is this happening on a emulator? On one device? On all devices? Does it matter if your USB debugging is enabled or disabled?

Comment: @CommonsWare Doesn't work on my Samsung Note 9, but does work on my Samsung Tab s5e tablet.

Comment: Off the cuff, it sounds like Samsung screwed up the Note 9. Are you getting the broadcasts mentioned in [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager#isCharging())?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have no problem implementing the `BroadcastReceiver` to get the charging status, but it only reacts to status changes (won't react on launch), so I still need to get the status at launch. I end up using the sticky `Intent` approach: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#DetermineChargeState

Answer (score 1):

you can use Broadcast:

```
Intent batteryBroadcast = context.registerReceiver(null,
                new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int batteryLevel = batteryBroadcast.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        boolean isCharging = batteryBroadcast.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1) != 0;
```